# InDesign FindChangeByList Search for Text in a Style

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep

Simple question:

What is the Javascript syntax for adding a Paragraph or Character Style to a search in the FindChangeByList.txt file?

As in: grep {findWhat:"Anything", findStyle"Bolder"}

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep    {findWhat:"Something", appliedCharacterStyle:"Bolder", appliedParagraphStyle:"body"}    {changeTo:"SomethingElse", appliedCharacterStyle:"italic", appliedParagraphStyle:"header"}  {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```

Mind the spaces before the appliedCharacterStyle or appliedParagraphStyle properties.

Comment: Perfect. I was hoping it was this easy - but apparently when I tried it first, there must have been a typo. Probably the space. Thank you!